# space between the radio button and label Cakephp

Tags: css, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

i am newbie in Cakephp trying to create a space between radio box and a label

```
    <span class="label"><b>Gender</b></span>

   <?php    $options=array('M'=>'Male'."<br>" , 'F'=>'Female');
    $attributes=array('legend'=>false,'label'=>'gender_male.','class'=>'radio');
    echo $this->Form->radio('gender',$options,$attributes);?>
   </div>
```

i have created a radio box in Cakephp but there is no space between the box and label is  coming ... how can i create a space .

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try it

```
  <span class="label"><b>Gender</b></span>

   <?php    
       $options=array('M'=>'&nbsp;&nbsp;Male'."<br>" , 'F'=>'&nbsp;&nbsp;Female');
       $attributes=array('legend'=>false,'label'=>'gender_male.','class'=>'radio');
       echo $this->Form->radio('gender',$options,$attributes);?>
    </div>
```

Comment: You do not "style" or "align" anything with &nbsp;, that's wrong. That is what CSS is thought for. Also, in case this is XHTML the <br> should be closed -> <br />

Comment: Yup, this is just an ugly hack to "fix it"... 
Better use CSS to position the label and radio buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Adding margin or padding to one of the elements depending on your design goals.

This is not a CakePHP issue but a CSS styling task. See http://www.w3schools.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the following code:

```
<style type="text/css">
label{padding-left:5px;}
</style>
<span class="label"><b>Gender</b></span>
<?php  $options=array('M'=>'Male'."<br>" , 'F'=>'Female');
$attributes=array('legend'=>false,'label'=>'gender_male.','class'=>'radio', 'div' => false, 'separator' => '');
echo $this->Form->radio('gender',$options, $attributes);?>
```

Comment: It is always better to use CSS while the issue is related to presentation view. If we would use '&nbsp;' in options, then in future if you need that option value using javascript. You will always have to trim before using it.

Answer (score -1):

You can use labels in styled span with padding but don't forget to use escape False otherwise it will show you the entire span. Please see the `<span style="padding:0 15px 0 15px;">No</span>` part of the code.

```
<?php 
  echo $this->Form->radio('lifestyle_drinking', 
  [
    [ 'value' => '0', 'text' => '<span style="padding:0 15px 0 15px;">No</span>'],
    [ 'value' => '1', 'text' => 'Yes'],
    [ 'value' => '2', 'text' => 'Ocassionally']
  ], 
  [ 'div' => false, 
    'class' => 'form-control col-xs-10 col-sm-10', 
    **'escape' => false**
  ]); 
?>
```

Comment: you should write a css. This is a ugly solution.