# cant place spaces between radio button options in cakephp 3.2

Tags: html, css, cakephp

In Cakephp3.2 I cant place spaces between radio buttons. I am sure there is an easy way.
Here is an example of what I am talking about from my test server, check the radio button area in Grammar section about 2/3rds down page.

```
http://andrewt.com.au/crm/students/studentassessment-eng7/35730
```

My code

```
 <?php  $opt1q1='  I wanted to watch TV, but the electricity went out unexpectedly.';

   ?>

    <br>
    <h3><?php   echo  'Task 3: Grammar'  ?> </h3>

  <div class='alert alert-info'><?php   echo  '1 )'.$opt1q1;  ?> </div>

  <?php    echo $this->Form->radio(  'a16',  ['text'=>'a) noun', 'b) verb  ','c) preposition  ', 'd) pronoun  ' ],
    ['default' =>$assessment['a16'] ,'style' => 'padding-left:5px;' ]    );
```

The docs didnt help either and its maybe because I have an older version cakephp?
https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/views/helpers/form.html#creating-radio-buttons

Didnt work
[space between the radio button and label Cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429404/space-between-the-radio-button-and-label-cakephp)

Answer (score 0):

i think what you are looking for are link breaks?

[How to add a line break within echo in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12994769/how-to-add-a-line-break-within-echo-in-php/12994798)

https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_nl2br.asp

Comment: Hi I made it clear I want spaces between options (horizontal). Why is this so hard to find? No line breaks please

Comment: aahh sorry does instead of using padding-left use "margin-left: 40px" on "label" work?

Comment: this has no effect using margin-left. I need a working example as guess work is getting me nowhere in this. Cakephp is difficult for radio buttons

Comment: no i mean in the css use "label" then "margin-left: 40px"

Comment: hi close but setting default value on which ever raduo button was clicked now doesnt work. Also this isnt cakephp but i could probably change it.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <input type="hidden" name="a16" value="" class="form-control"><label for="a16-0">

  <input type="radio" name="a16"   value="0"   <?php echo $assessment['a16']==0   ?' checked=checked':'' ?>  >a) noun</label><label for="a16-0">
  <input type="radio" name="a16"  value="1"   <?php echo $assessment['a16']==1 ?' checked=checked':'' ?>  >b) verb</label><label for="a16-1">
  <input type="radio" name="a16"   value="2"    <?php echo $assessment['a16']==2 ?' checked=checked':'' ?>  >c)preposition</label><label for="a16-2">            
  <input type="radio" name="a16"   value="3"  <?php echo $assessment['a16']==3 ?' checked=checked':'' ?>  >d)pronoun </label><label for="a16-3"> 


<style>
    label{
  margin-left: 16px;
}

</style>
```